# Desejo fazer uma trigger para controle de Estoque, porem nao sei como fazer isso

Tags: mysql

Desejo criar uma tabela chamada 'produto' que tem o seu id e a quantidade no estoque e outra tabela chamada 'compra, a tabela compra vai ter a chave primaria do produto e o id da compra, então eu queria decrementar a quantidade no estoque da tabela 'produto' toda vez que uma compra for efetuada, como faria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu sistema quando for efetuada a compra utilize o seguinte comando SQL:

```
UPDATE `produtos` SET `estoque` = `estoque` - 1 WHERE `idProduto`
```

No lugar do 1 coloque a variável que vai definir a quantidade de produtos comprados pela pessoa.

Se precisar de fazer isso em mais de um tipo de produto use uma estrutura de repetição.

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: mas tipo, como eu faria isso? eu quero q na hora que inserir um produto já decremente automaticamente do estoque, eu faria isso usando uma trigger?

Comment: Você pode fazer da maneira que achar melhor, da pra fazer usando trigger, ou quando a pessoa por exemplo clicar la em finalizar a compra você executa a função mysql.

Comment: como ficaria usando trigger? nao sei implementar uma trigger

Comment: Cara pra falar a verdade não sou a melhor pessoa pra te explicar como fazer isso com o trigger, por que eu faço  requisições sql e depois dou um update por exemplo. Eu faço o insert primeiro na tabela compras e depois do um update na tabela produtos para diminuir o estoque. Entendeu?

Comment: muito obrigado meu amigo, sua logica me ajudou mt, resolvi meu problema